# SSRS report returning error at XML position that is higher than max position in the file

Tags: xml, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I have a report in SSRS that is not playing nicely on a single installation instance. All other installations the report runs as expected. All other reports on the offending server run as expected as well. I've tried the usual delete/re-upload, create copy and upload, restart SSRS. Same result.

Error message:

```
The attempt to connect to the report server failed. Check your connection information and that the report server is a compatible version. 
    There is an error in XML document (1, 1022960).
        '┐', hexadecimal value 0x02, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1022960.
```

My biggest hang-up is that there is no position 1022960 in the XML. If I open the RDL file in Notepad++ to review as XML, the highest position is 310609.

The environment where this is having trouble is French-based, which is the only variable I can find differentiating it from my other environments. But the report runs in English.

I have verified that the Data Source has a successful test connection and is the same Source used by the other successful reports.

Again, the same RDL file works fine in other environments and other RDL files work fine in this environment. Is there anything I can do with the position number 1022960 to narrow down the invalid character considering it's above the max position of the RDL file itself?

Comment: Make sure you validate the xml with an xml checker.  You probably do not have matching start/end tags so the checker is looking past the end character.  Is the beginning of the file showing UTF-8?

Comment: @jdweng - Good thoughts, but the XML was validated and the exact RDL file works on other servers just fine. I also used a schema XSD to use Notepad++ XML Tools to check that and it passed. First line of the file has <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Error says "The attempt to connect to the report server failed".  Either the route to the server is bad, the credentials are not working, or TLS is failing due to a certificate missing.